# SVG: Non-scaling markers not working in Safari (works correctly on Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, svg, safari

I created an SVG that is meant to act like an `<hr>` on a page. It should be able to scale proportionately to the width of its container (e.g. the page width) without the stroke scaling, including the start and end `<marker>` elements. This works as expected in Chrome but in Safari the markers are changing size. Is there something wrong with my SVG syntax?

Here is my svg code and a link to a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Thisjustin3141/pen/ExdPdxR).

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 300 4' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <marker 
      id='diamond'
      viewBox='0 0 10 10'
      refX="5"
      refY="5"
      markerWidth="6"
      markerHeight="6">
      <polygon points="0,5 5,0 10,5 5,10" fill="#9A8654" /> 
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line x1='1' y1='2' x2='299' y2='2' stroke='#9A8654' stroke-width='1' vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-dasharray='2 2' marker-start='url(#diamond)' marker-end='url(#diamond)'/>
</svg>
```

When used on an [actual site](https://nanoose-bay-cafe.webflow.io) the markers are even more broken and stretch horizontally in Safari but I'm hoping that fixing the basic problem will resolve the other issue.

I also tried `preserveAspectRatio="none"` without any luck.

Comment: You need to add a markerUnits attribute and set it to userSpaceOnUse. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/markerUnits

Comment: I have tried using `markerUnits='userSpaceOnUse'` the behaviour persists in Safari. Are you able to check if this solution works with the code provided?

Comment: https://wpt.fyi/results/svg/painting/reftests/marker-units-strokewidth-non-scaling-stroke.svg?label=experimental&label=master&aligned

Comment: https://wpt.fyi/results/svg/painting/reftests/marker-units-userspaceonuse-non-scaling-stroke.svg?label=experimental&label=master&aligned

Comment: As you can see from those links, Safari fails the way you're doing it but is OK with @MichaelMullany suggested way.

Comment: Thanks, good to know I'm not the only one. But I have not been able to fix the problem with markerUnits attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using percentages for some of the values. I had to make different markers for the start and end as there was no way to position them correctly otherwise.

```
<svg height='10' width='100%' viewBox='0 0 100% 10'  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <marker
            id='start'
            viewBox='0 0 2 2'
            refX='0'
            refY='1'
            markerHeight='4'
            markerWidth='4'
            >
      <polygon points='0,1 1,0 2,1 1,2' fill="#9A8654"/>
    </marker>
    <marker
            id='end'
            viewBox='0 0 2 2'
            refX='2'
            refY='1'
            markerHeight='4'
            markerWidth='4'
            >
      <polygon points='0,1 1,0 2,1 1,2' fill="#9A8654"/>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line 
        x1='0%'
        x2='100%' 
        y1='5' 
        y2='5' 
        stroke-width='2' 
        stroke="#9A8654"
        stroke-dasharray='2 2'
        marker-start='url(#start)'
        marker-end='url(#end)'
        vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'/>
</svg>
```